# What's the difference of libcurl.dylib and libcurl.3.dylib?

Tags: xcode, macos, libcurl

I want to use the `libcurl` in my `XCode` project on `Mac`. But I find there three `lib curl` dynamic libraries. 
Namely, they are **libcurl.dylib** / **libcurl.3.dylib** / **libcurl.4.dylib**.

I find there are a lot of other libraries on `Mac` which also have the multiple version, in the same way as `libcurl`.

So what's the difference with those versions library, and which one should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't each one a soft link to the more specific version? Example `libXXX` -> `libXXX.2` -> `libXXX.2.3`. If you always want the latest `libXXX` then you link to `libXXX`. But if you need a specific version you link to that specific version.

As you update OS X or Xcode, these libraries and their soft links get updated but you don't need to change which library reference you have.

Run a terminal window and do `ls -l /usr/lib` for lots of examples of this.

Comment: You are correct. Some of them are soft links. On my machine, `libcurl.3.dylib` -> `libcurl.4.dylib`   and `libcurl.dylib` -> `libcurl.4.dylib`.